# How to clear buffer of protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Clear all bytes writen so far, is there a way to do this with protobuf?

Comment: Which protobuf implementation are you using?  Also, your questions could be a lot more clear.  Can you add a code example showing us what you're trying to do?

Comment: Using it for persistent sockets,I'm using Google protobuf: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream.html#CodedOutputStream.GetDirectBufferPointer.details

Answer (score 2):

When you say clear, are you asking to undo the bytes you have already written?

If you are using the FileOutputStream or OstreamOutputStream, then what you have written might not be clear-able, as it has already been saved to disk or streamed somewhere. If you are using an ArrayOutputStream (which you might be if you are going to be writing it to a socket), then you can undo by just recreating your ArrayOutputStream and pointing it at the same buffer again.

It would help if you showed us the code you are currently using, so we can better advise you.